# Return the number of loops before a loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to return the number of products in a loop and output this before the loop. The below always returns 0, so is there a way that I can delay outputting this until after it has finished the loop?

```
if( $post_objects ):
$prodcount = 0;
?>

<h1>There are <?php echo $prodcount ?> items</h2>

<?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): ?>

<p>something</p>

<?php $prodcount++ ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Google how to get the length of an array in PHP...\

Comment: `$numLoops = count($post_objects)`

Comment: `echo count($post_objects, COUNT_RECURSIVE);`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton always use `COUNT_RECURSIVE` to count array with dynamic depths

Comment: @ArunpandianM How do you know it has dynamic depths? We don't know the contents

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Actually as the code does not process multiple levels I would say, there are no dynamic depths to plumb and even if there where, that would probably return the wrong answer anyway in this caase

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yea you are right we dont know the depth `count($array)` returns for first depth only thats why i am recommending to use `COUNT_RECURSIVE` to count all depths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, just `count()` the array and use that as the v ariable.

```
<?
if( $post_objects ):
?>
    <h1>There are <?php echo count($post_objects); ?> items</h2>
<?php 
    foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): 
?>
        <p>something</p>
<?php 
        $prodcount++
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Could not resist reformatting the code :) :) :) SORRY

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you so much! I tried, but I don't like this markup syntax

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I'm still learning so I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted :(

Comment: @Ordog you're getting downvoted because this is very likely a duplicate question and you didn't show much research effort. On stackoverflow if an answer fixed your issue you should click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct. :)

Comment: Ok, I did try and research but I see how that can come across. I can't mark your answer as correct for another 4 minutes yet but don't worry I will. Thanks again.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yea looks like WordPress code. YUK in a bucket :)

Answer (score 0):

As `foreach` iterates over array, not sure why you are trying to reinvent the wheel, instead of using ordinary `count()` on that array:

```
$prodcount = count($post_objects);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php